# Convert the matches of a regex into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

The code below correctly matches:

- `letter 'c' followed by digit`
- `letter 'c' followed by digit dash digit`
- `digit may be followed by an other digit enclosed in square parentheses []`

and creates an array as expected as this:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 4
        [end]=> 8
    )        
    [1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2
        [end]=> 
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 3
        [end] => 5
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 6[2]
        [end] =>
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 8[4]
        [end] => 10
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [start] => 14
        [end] => 21[5]
    )
)
```

**CODE:**

```
 $str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]";

 $re = "~c(?<start>\d+(?:\[\d+])?)(?:-(?<end>(?&start)?))?~"; 

 $myarray = explode("|",$str);

foreach ($myarray as $my) {
    preg_match_all($re, $my, $matches);

    $res = array_map(function($ms, $me) { 
        return array("start" => $ms, "end" => $me);
    }, $matches["start"], $matches["end"]);
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

Now I would like to **add** an other `key` with the value of the *digit* after the `a`.
So for example, given the above `$str`

```
$str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]".
```

the `a` values are: `2` and `6` and the expected result array would be the following. **Note that** `6` is repeated for every `c` matched.

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [a] => 2
        [start] => 4
        [end]=> 8
    )        
    [1] => Array
    (
        [a] => 6
        [start] => 2
        [end]=> 
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [a] => 6
        [start] => 3
        [end] => 5
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [a] => 6
        [start] => 6[2]
        [end] =>
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [a] => 6
        [start] => 8[4]
        [end] => 10
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [a] => 6
        [start] => 14
        [end] => 21[5]
    )
)
```

Comment: Since each array key must be unique, it isn't possible.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I changed a little my question. Please look at the edited post and at the expected result array.

Comment: What happens if "a" is never defined or if "a" occurs after the first "c"? Are these situations possible?

Comment: `a` is always defined and it is always the first letter of the string exploded by `|` (`explode("|",$str);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
$str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]";

$re = '~(?:a(?<a>\d+))?c(?<start>\d+(?:\[\d+])?)(?:-(?<end>\g<start>))?~';

if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
    $a = ''; // current value for "a" -----,
    $result = array_map(function ($i) use (&$a) {
        if (!empty($i['a'])) $a = $i['a'];
        else $i['a'] = $a;

        if (!isset($i['end'])) $i['end'] = '';

        foreach ($i as $k=>$v) {
            if (is_numeric($k)) unset($i[$k]);
        }

        return $i;

    }, $matches);
}

print_r($result);
```

But if you already know exactly how is the string format and if you don't need to validate it, there are probably smarter (and faster) ways to obtain the same result.

For example, using `explode` and formatted strings with `sscanf`:

```
$str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]";

$parts = explode('|', $str);
$result = [];

$keys = ['a', 'start', 'end'];

foreach($parts as $part) {
    foreach(explode(',', $part) as $k=>$v) {
        if ($k)
            list($start, $end) = sscanf($v, 'c%[^-]-%[^,]');
        else
            list($a, $start, $end) = sscanf($v, 'a%dc%[^-]-%[^,]');

        $result[] = array_combine($keys, [$a, $start, $end]);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate the alternative with `sscanf` which I would never thought about..