# Given a string create a multidimensional array with named keys usign a regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

**I'm using PHP.** Given, for example, the following string:

```
$str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]|a30"
```

and exploding it by `|` I get the strings:

```
a2c4-8
a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]
a30
```

Now I would like to separate the digits that follow the `a` from all the other characters, remove the letters `a` and `c` (keep dashes, commas and square brackets) and place the results in a multidimensional array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [c] => 4-8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6
            [c] => 2,3-5,6[2],8[4]-10,14-21[5]
    )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 30
            [c] => 
        )

)
```

`a` is always followed by digit and after this digit there may be or may not be a `c` followed by other comma separated strings.

Notice that in the resulting array the letters `a` and `c` have been removed. All other characters have been kept. I tried to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968847/convert-the-matches-of-a-regex-into-a-multidimensional-array) by *Casimir et Hippolyte* but without success.

**A plus** would be avoid to add to the resulting array empty array keys (as the last `[c]` above).

Comment: After exploding you probably want to use a regex to match the different parts and then just put them into the result array (Something like this: https://3v4l.org/XoIb1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution using `preg_match_all` function with named submasks(`(?P<a>)...`) and `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag, `array_map`, `array_filter`, `array_column`(available since PHP 5.5) and `trim` functions:

```
$str = "a2c4-8|a6c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]|a30";
$parts = explode("|", $str);

$result = array_map(function ($v) {
    preg_match_all("/(?P<a>a\d+)?(?P<c>c[0-9-\[\]]+)?/", $v, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $arr = [];
    $a_numbers = array_filter(array_column($matches, "a"));
    $c_numbers = array_filter(array_column($matches, "c"));
    if (!empty($a_numbers)) {
        $arr['a'] = array_map(function($v){ return trim($v, 'a'); }, $a_numbers)[0];
    }
    if (!empty($c_numbers)) {
        $arr['c'] = implode(",", array_map(function($v){ return trim($v, 'c'); }, $c_numbers));
    }

    return $arr;
}, $parts);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [c] => 4-8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6
            [c] => 2,3-5,6[2],8[4]-10,14-21[5]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 30
        )
)
```

P.S. "empty array keys" are also omitted